# How do I solve Enigma codes?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

I found all Enigma codes, [thanks to PowerPyx' collectible guide](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/wolfenstein-new-order/235133-wolfenstein-new-order-collectible-guide-gold-items-enigma-codes-letters.html). All I have to do now is solve them, but how am I supposed to do it?

Each code has 2 rows of 9 numbers ranging from 1 to 9. Each row determines the value of a letter ranging from A to J. I tried brute forcing the letters, but from AA to JJ nothing happened. Brute forcing the numbers is going to take forever, since there are one Billion different combinations for them.

Finding the collectible Enigma Codes only allows me to set a value for the corresponding number, but it doesn't look like there's a hint to solving it.

Exactly how am I supposed to find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in game. In chapter 4 when you break into the prison, you go into a room with a blackboard. on the blackboard is the following sum.

8x9=72 (7+2)= 9

If you apply this rule to the number of the enigma row and position number you should get the single digit that is the answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Upvote for hints and not outright solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It may be sweet irony, but 5 minutes before I posted my question, [someone already posted the solution to the codes](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/wolfenstein-new-order/235191-enigma-decrypting-solving-codes.html).

To solve Code `n`, you will need to do the following:

First row: Put `n` in the first column. To get the value of the next column, add `n` to the current column's value. If the value exceeds 9, use the [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).

Second row: To get the current column's value, subtract the value of the first row's same column from 9.

0 is never part of the code. Each column adds up to either 9 or 18.

---

Here are the solutions and what they unlock:

#### Code 1

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 9
```

Unlocks **999**

```
Play Wolfenstein in 999 mode.
- 999% more action
- start with 999 health
- unlimited ammo
- ÜBER difficulty
```

#### Code 2

```
2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9
7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2 9
```

Unlocks **WALK IN THE PARK**

```
Play Wolfenstein in WALK IN THE PARK mode.
- all HUD elements except interactive prompts disabled
- rely fully on your senses to survive
- I AM DEATH INCARNATE! difficulty
```

#### Code 3

```
3 6 9 3 6 9 3 6 9
6 3 9 6 3 9 6 3 9
```

Unlocks **HARDCORE**

```
Play Wolfenstein in HARDCORE mode.
- all health and armor pickups removed from the game
- ÜBER difficulty
```

#### Code 4

```
4 8 3 7 2 6 1 5 9
5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9
```

Unlocks **IRONMAN**

```
Play Wolfenstein in IRONMAN mode.
- only one life
- game over if you die
- ÜBER difficulty
```

Comment: That's not ironic, it's merely coincidental. Having said that, thanks for the post!

Comment: Yep, I'd say around 10% of the times when people say "that's ironic" is the thing actually ironic.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the row number (the number at the beginning of the row) by the index number, if the value is greater than 9, sum the digits until you end up with single digit <= 9.

the hint to solve this can be found in various chapters on walls and boards

Let's take 4<sup>th</sup> enigma code as example:

```
4-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]
   1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
5-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]

First row:
4*1 = 04
4*2 = 08
4*3 = 12 -> 1+2 = 03
4*4 = 16 -> 1+6 = 07
4*5 = 20 -> 2+0 = 02
4*6 = 24 -> 2+4 = 06
4*7 = 28 -> 2+8 = 10 -> 1+0 = 01
4*8 = 32 -> 2+3 = 05
4*9 = 36 -> 3+6 = 09

Second row:
5*1 = 05
5*2 = 10 -> 1+0 = 01
5*3 = 15 -> 1+5 = 06
5*4 = 20 -> 2+0 = 02
5*5 = 25 -> 2+5 = 07
5*6 = 30 -> 3+0 = 03
5*7 = 35 -> 3+5 = 08
5*8 = 40 -> 4+0 = 04
5*9 = 45 -> 4+5 = 09

4-[04]-[08]-[03]-[07]-[02]-[06]-[01]-[05]-[09]
5-[05]-[01]-[06]-[02]-[07]-[03]-[08]-[04]-[09]
```